# Merge [clothes] into [clothing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I don't think any user could make a case to keep both synonyms as separate tags. I propose that [clothes](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothes) be made a synonym of [clothing](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done. We don't need a synonym in this case. Synonyms are designed for when two completely different words describe the same tag. In this case, text completion would help steer users towards the correct usage no matter which word they chose: <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> → [clothing](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clothing).